# How do I remove the timeout in the boot menu

Tags: grub, boot-loader, timeout, boot-menu

I installed several operating systems on my computer in a multiboot configuration (Ubuntu, Linux Mint, Windows, ...). When I turn on my PC, the boot menu appears with a timeout. Sometimes, I don't focus on it (I turn on my PC and then I go to the fridge to get a soft drink, for example) so that I miss the boot menu so I cannot chose my desired OS. Because of that, I must restart my computer and choose my desired OS again. Is there anyway to remove the timeout. I mean when the boot menu appear, so that there is no timeout, no OS will boot until I chose my desired OS.

I am using Ubuntu and Linux Mint.

Answer (score 19):

I'm assuming you're using GRUB2 as your bootloader. You can disable the timeout by opening the file */etc/default/grub* and changing the value of `GRUB_TIMEOUT`:

`GRUB_TIMEOUT=-1`

Then you need to run `sudo update-grub` to re-generate */boot/grub/grub.cfg* after editing */etc/default/grub*.

See [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148095/how-do-i-set-the-grub-timeout-and-the-grub-default-boot-entry) for more information and settings.

Comment: +1. you also need to run `update-grub` (a wrapper around `grub-mkconfig`) to re-generate /boot/grub/grub.cfg after editing `/etc/default/grub`